# PyQt5 windows freeze when terminating a thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

In pyqt5 when i try to close a tread for a my program Ui freezes and stop responding.I'm new to pyqt5 couldn't find a answer for this.

These are the methods in main window(GUI) file

```
def clickButton_on(self):
    print("clicked on/off")
    ControlPanel.start()

def clickButton_Off(self):
    print("clicked on/off")
    ControlPanel.stop()
```

This is the controlPanel class methods

```
@classmethod
def start(cls):
    print('start method fired')
    cls.th = threading.Thread(target=cls.test,args=(cls.attr,))
    cls.th.start()

@classmethod
def stop(cls):
    print('stop method fired')
    cls.th.join()
```

Full code to recreate the issue

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi 
import sys
import threading

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("on")

        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b2.setText("off")
        self.b2.move(50,50)

        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.clickButton_on)
        self.b2.clicked.connect(self.clickButton_Off)


    def clickButton_on(self):
        print("clicked on/off")
        ControlPanel.start()

    def clickButton_Off(self):
        print("clicked on/off")
        ControlPanel.stop()

class ControlPanel:

    n=2

    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        print('start method fired')
        cls.th = threading.Thread(target=cls.test,args=(cls.n,))
        cls.th.start()

    @classmethod
    def stop(cls):
        print('stop method fired')
        cls.th.join()

    @classmethod
    def test(cls,n):
        print('test method fired')
        n= 0 
        while True:
            n += 0.1
            print(f'thread running n = {n}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

windows completely freezes. It doesnt close the thread with .join() it thread keeps running.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: sure ill edit the question code

Comment: That only means that you thread is running. does it ever stop?

Comment: no .join() should stop running the tread but it doesn't. when the program come to that step UI freezes and doesn't go the next lines.

Comment: @shanthebuwana No, join does not stop the thread, it just blocks the eventloop until the thread finishes executing

Comment: ohh that make sence thats why ui freeze cuz its running on the main thread(event loop).k how do i close this one while keeping the main event loop running.